# The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version i know

Tags: php, mysql, yii, pdo, mariadb

Already has been asked but i dont see any satisfactory response, i am using archlinux latest completely updated.
From mysql console :`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...` works, but from my php yii application doesn't, give me this:

```
The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version.
```

Also gets me the same error from phpmyadmin.

Already put `local-infile=1` in both mysqld and mysql and in yii configuration main.php added  `'attributes'=>array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,),` to db array. But nothing.

I tried recompiling mariadb with `-DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=ON` configure option just in case something but I think it already had, and nothing.

I am running mariadb 5.5.35-1.

Could someone shed some light on this...

Comment: Could be that this check is actually in the client library, that would explain the difference between cmdline client and PHP. Will try to look into this later today if time permits ...